# Unable to connect to database from php, Remote server error,. Provided refresh token is expired

Tags: php, postgresql, deployment, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm following the instructions provided in this
[Link](https://cloud.ibm.com/services/databases-for-postgresql/crn%3Av1%3Abluemix%3Apublic%3Adatabases-for-postgresql%3Aus-south%3Aa%2F14afc2a5aabd4d769f8e0298a65af740%3Abef23709-6880-409a-a808-4646f41a82e9%3A%3A?paneId=gettingStarted)
to deploy my PHP page in IBM Cloud along with PostgreSQL but I'm having trouble while connecting them together.

## Connecting to your database with the CLI

There are two main documentation locations that reference the appropriate commands to connect to your database from the CLI:

- The Cloud Databases CLI Reference document.
- The Connecting with psql document

The ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections command handles everything that is involved in creating a command line client connection. For example, to connect to a deployment named "example-postgres", use the following command:

```
    ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections example-postgres --start
```

The command prompts for the admin password and then runs the psql command line client to connect to the database. If you have not installed the cloud databases plug-in, review the Connecting with psql documentation here for more detailed connection information.

I'm trying the command but I'm getting these errors

```
        C:\Users\name>ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections <My_deployment_name> --start
        FAILED
        Remote server error. Status code: 400, error code: BXNIM0408E, message: Provided refresh token is expired
        Database Password>
        FAILED
        Get "/v1/resource_instances?name=<My_deployment_name>": unsupported protocol scheme ""
        C:\Users\name
```

What could be the cause of this and how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried logging in again?

Comment: Yes, I did.....

Comment: Log in, run your commands. Does it really still say that the refresh token expired?